# Side-By-Side Configuration Fails To Load

Tags: windows, windows-vista, microsoft-office, adobe-reader

Windows Vista - Microsoft Office - Adobe Acrobat

Hi Guys,

I've got a user who is getting the following error when trying to start Microsoft Office or Adobe Acrobat:

> The application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.  Please see the application event log for detail.

When I try to check the event viewer, I get an error that "MMC could not create the snap-in Event Viewer".  When I try to manually add the event viewer snap-in, I get the same error.

I've read online that the first issue could be caused by a missing or corrupt C++ Redistributable... so I've re-installed it but to no avail.

Have you guys come across this issue before?  Any suggestions on how to proceed here?

Comment: I have the same problem, except it only happens for one program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Vista on a PC with Office 2007 and Acrobat 8 Pro. The only thing that worked for me was to uninstall both office and acrobat and then reinstall them both. I wasn't able to follow up whether the resolution was permanent because I fresh-installed Windows 7 shortly thereafter.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the input. We'll see if the issue resurfaces after a reinstall of the programs.

Comment: It seems that a reinstall of the apps this appears on did the trick.  I'm still a little concerned that this will come up later with a different app but so far so good.