# Installation Error on Windows Vista: "Side-by-Side configuration is incorrect"

Tags: windows-vista, installation, visual-c++

*NOTE: This is not a dupe of [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/77860/side-by-side-configuration-fails-to-load). That question refers to a similar problem with 2 programs, while I'm only having it with 1, so the solution there doesn't apply to my situation.*

My relative asked me to install H&R Block 2009 on his Windows Vista 32-bit computer. I ran the installation program, which succeeded, but **when I try to open the application itself**, it gives me the following **error**:

> The application failed to start
>   because its **side-by-side configuration
>   is incorrect**. Please see the
>   application event log for more detail.

Here are the steps I've done so far to try and remedy this problem:

1. In elevated command prompt, run the command: `sfc /scannow`
2. Uninstall H&R Block 2009
3. Uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
4. Reinstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable by downloading from MSFT website
5. Reinstall H&R Block 2009

This didn't fix it. I've searched for a long time and haven't found anything that works. The H&R Block site itself states that the way to fix this problem is to uninstall and reinstall H&R Block 2009.

Has anyone run into this issue before? If so, how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add any information from the Application event log?  (Right click on *Computer* select *Manage* and look in the Event Viewer for Applications and Services for anything about the application.

Comment: Also, when you downloaded the Visual C++ Runtime from Microsoft's website did you get the SP 1 version? (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647&displaylang=en)